# Slick Database Migrations

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I'm working on a project using Scala which uses Slick.io for handling database interactions. I have the database schema implemented via Slick using its DDL.

This all works fine when I was starting out but now that I am some way into the project, making changes to the database schema is becoming a pain. I have to drop all the tables, manage data, re-create the schema etc...

I've previously used the PHP framework Laravel which had a nice way of dealing with database migrations & making changes to databases. This was done via a set of classes that were controlled by a timestamp and the "most recent" migrations could be run to make any changes to a database schema.

Does Slick have any equivalent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, slick itself does not have an equivalent, but you can use something like:

Flyway:

https://github.com/flyway/flyway

http://flywaydb.org/

As you have not given any additional info:
for the play-framework there is an own module, which can be found here: https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play

Comment: There is also [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), which I personally prefer to FlyAwayDB.